# Create hex dump of list values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write a module that display data from a communication line. It shall display the transferred data in a hex dump.

How can I convert a list `a=[0x41,0x42,0x43,0x0D]` to a hex dump like

```
41 42 43 0D      ABC.
```

Please note that the non-printable character is substituted with dot.

I tried this with `''.join(map(chr,a))`. This is displayed in the Python shell as 'ABC\n', but this still includes the line-feed character.

In a different approach I want to display the list exactly as it is shown in the Python shell to the output. i.e. the line feed should be display as "\n" instead of going to the next line. How do I replace `\n` with `\\n` and replace any other non-printable character with a dot?

Comment: What do you want to happen with non-ASCII characters (>= x80)?

Comment: This is a requirements dump. What thoughts did you have before asking someone else to implement this for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that you want to turn control characters to dots (those with ASCII code below 32).

I will also assume that the character rendering (the second part) should start at a fixed offset, so that you would need to split the data over multiple lines when it becomes too wide.

Code:

```
def hexdump(data):
    return "\n".join(
        " ".join(["{:02X}".format(n) for n in chunk]).ljust(49) + 
        "".join([chr(n) if chr(n).isprintable() else "." for n in chunk])
        for chunk in [data[i:i+16] for i in range(0, len(data), 16)]
    )
```

Example run:

```
a=[0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43
,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x0D]
print(hexdump(a))
```

Output:

```
41 42 43 41 42 43 41 42 43 41 42 43 41 42 43 41  ABCABCABCABCABCA
42 43 41 42 43 41 42 43 41 42 43 41 42 43 41 42  BCABCABCABCABCAB
43 0D                                            C.
```

### Escaping control characters

The alternative you ask about at the end of your question, can be achieved with a regular expression or `translate`:

```
trans = str.maketrans({ 
    i: "\\" + ("x{:02x}".format(i) if i < 7 or i > 13  
              else "abtnvfr"[i-7]) 
    for i in range(32)
})

s = "first line\nsecond line\r\ncol1\tcol2\nspecial \x1f"
print(s)
print(s.translate(trans))
```

This will escape control characters (in the ASCII range 0 - 31) with `\x01` notation, or with `\n`, `\r`,... when such a mnemonic exists for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the string format:

```
>>> ' '.join(['{:02X}'.format(h) for h in a])
'41 42 43 0D'
```

Documentation can be found in PEP3101: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers

Comment: You have seen that I already see the hex dump '41 42 43 0D'. Your answer creates exactly the same result. You didn't noticed the ASCII representation that is part of the hex dump, have you?

Comment: @harper Where do we see that you already have this? In the line showing your desired result? Then I guess we also see that you already have that other part, and you're asking for nothing?

Comment: @superbrain: "I tried this with ''.join(map(chr,a)). This is displayed in the Python shell as 'ABC\n', but this still includes the line-feed character."

Comment: @harper That's just talking about an attempt for the second part, doesn't say that you have something for the first part.

Comment: @superbrain You're right. For the first part I still saw a problem "but this still includes the line-feed character.". That's why I asked.

Comment: @superbrain If you're curious about my Python experience, you can try to search for "user:harper [python]".

Comment: @harper With "first part" and "second part" I meant "41 42 43 0D" and "ABC.". It's not clear from your question that you have code for the former already. That search gives me 3,798,182 results. I acknowledge I have less Python experience than you then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222027/discussion-between-harper-and-superb-rain).